# Why are actuarial science questions considered off topic?

Tags: discussion, tagging, closing, close-reasons, on-hold-questions

I asked a question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1505078/where-can-i-find-a-global-actuarial-life-expectancy-table) which was about the percentile breakdown of global life expectancy.  While this question does certainly pertain to topics not related to mathematics, it is very specifically about actuarial science, and was tagged as such.  Since there is a tag for [actuarial-science](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/actuarial-science), I find it a little strange that a question clearly specific to this field is considered off topic.

How exactly should I go about asking actuarial science questions, or should I at all?

Comment: How is finding a specific data set a mathematical question?

Comment: Remarkably, there is perhaps a more relevant SE site. It seems not entirely uncommon for users to look for data sets on opendata.se.

Comment: Tobias - Fair point.  Mixedmath - Thank you for the pointer.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The existence of a tag does not mean every question to which this tag applies is on topic. For example, there is a tag [physics](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/physics). It is used when a mathematical question has some physics aspect to it. But it does not mean that every physics question can be asked here.

Similar with actuarial science. If doing it leads to you asking a math question, fine. Other things, like data gathering or coding in R, are best pursued elsewhere.